# How can a deity be prevented from materializing without all its parts?

Tags: dimensions

A horcrux is an item used to obtain a piece of a person's soul. This process is a form of immortality, in which a person who wants to cheat death would put fragments of their soul into various horcruxes to anchor them to the material realm. When an individual dies, the person's spirit is able to remain attached to the realm and is free to possess an alternate body as many times as their are horcruxes remaining.

Long ago, a demon that exists across several dimensions chose to use horcruxes to enter our world, but through a reverse process. Demons are unable to pass into our world directly. Too get around this, he divided his spirit into seven pieces, which would be born into the material realm simultaneously as human children. These living horcruxes would contain a piece of his essence, and would all possess powerful magical abilities due to their demonic heritage. These individuals would remain connected to the demon, allowing it to influence their actions and decisions. At some point, these individuals would fuse together as adults, uniting the horcruxes into a single being and allowing the demon to materialize fully whole in the realm.

The seventh horcrux, due to divine shenanigans, gained a measure of Independence from it's controller refuses to cooperate, unwilling to give up its individuality and rejoin it's "parent". Naturally, the common sense solution would be that the demon would simply being together the six individuals he has influence over. Although the reborn demon wouldn't be complete, it would still be vastly powerful and strong enough to over-power the remaining piece. It could then absorb the individual directly and complete it's form. An analogy would be that of a jigsaw, with most of the pieces coming together and the one horcrux remaining to complete the picture.

I need to valid reason to explain how this demon cannot follow this method, allowing most of its pieces to materialize. If horcruxes are fragments of this demons soul, how can it not materialize without the final horcrux?

Comment: What has this to do with spacetime and dimensions? It's just magic, and it works like this because it's magic.

Comment: This seems awfully story/opinion-based. I don't see how an objectively 'correct' answer can be identified for this.

Answer (score 1):

Make seventh piece essential, something like demon's heart or brain. Without it demon simply couldn't function as material being.

Second option is that, to complete ritual of demon recreation need all parts to willingly cooperate.

Third option is to give seventh some kind of dead man switch, when its killed or assaulted by demon, it would destroy taking demon with itself.